# Web api methods are not calling in Web performance tool Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, performance-testing

I have successfully created Web performance tool for my web application. In my web application, I have some Web API calls. After running the Web Performance tool the API calls only throws error i.e not getting response from the server.

Here is the screenshot,

[image]

I am very new to this tool and I searched many sites regarding this but I could not found the solution.

Comment: (1) Search the Microsoft site for debugging web tests. (2) Start by worrying about the first request that failed, your screenshot highlights the second request. (3) Look at the "Details" and the "Response" tabs, between them they normally explain what is wrong. (4) Expect the "web browser" or the "Response" tabs to give some message from the web site about what it does not like. (5) Web sites often send a "200 OK" to badly formed requests. (6) This question should be closed, please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding all the Http Request Headers in Web test plug-in, the API methods gives success response.